# AngularJS - replacement of window.onload in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got function that set up hyperlinks in pure JavaScript, and this function is called by window.onload. I want to do the same thing but fully in angularJS. How can I do this?

```
function setUpLinks(){
 document.getElementById("linkYoutube").setAttribute("href",link1,"target","_blank");
 document.getElementById("linkSteam").setAttribute("href",link2,"target" ,"_blank");
 document.getElementById("linkGithub").setAttribute("href",link3,"target","_blank");

}

window.onload = function(){
 setUpLinks();
}
```

Comment: look at $onInit Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized

Comment: You can set it up with: `<a id="linkYoutube" ng-href="{{link1}}" target="_blank">{{link1}}</a>` and `$scope.link1 = "...";` in controller

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your English is just fine, by the way. No need to apologize.

Comment: "You can set it up with: <a id="linkYoutube" ng-href="{{link1}}" target="_blank">{{link1}}</a> and $scope.link1 = "..."; in controller – Aleksey Solovey" Thanks, this is good, but I'd like to make a function in angular, that automatically after loading website set up argument "ng-href","{{link1}}", just becouse I dont want to mess html file, angular should do it.

Comment: @Ariteku controllers are used for populating the content of the page, how else do you want it to be done "automatically"?

Answer (score 0):

You can put initialization in app.run:

```js
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .run(InitializeApplication);

    InitializeApplication.$inject = [];

    function InitializeApplication() {

      setUpLinks();

      function setUpLinks(){
       document.getElementById("linkYoutube").setAttribute("href",link1,"target","_blank");
       document.getElementById("linkSteam").setAttribute("href",link2,"target" ,"_blank");
       document.getElementById("linkGithub").setAttribute("href",link3,"target","_blank");
      }      
    }

})();
```

Comment: why wouldnt they just use onInit

Comment: onInit of which component??

Comment: If OP wants to do this **fully** in angular wouldn't `document.getElementById` as well as `setAttribute` be replaced by it's angular equivalent?

Comment: I'm not downvoting btw xD yeah it just seems they they know what they need to do but dont know how to do it the angular way.  therefore just trying to see if they want this for some edge case reason or if we should be exapling lifecycle hooks/dom maniulation in angular :)

Comment: Yea, I would like to avoid pure js elements like document.getElementById, It would be nice if I get knowledge how to write same thing in Angular :D

Comment: awesome look into $window, $element, chances are if you're using document.getEct you're doing something wrong in angular not saying every use is wrong just saying there properly a different way. is there a reason you wouldn't do this in the markup ?